# How to feed multiple "LIST" inputs through feed_dict in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I do have to inputs as following:

```
input_t = []
input_z = []
for j in range(batch_size):      
    input_t.append(train_data[train_batch_order[j + i * batch_size], :, :, :])  
    input_z.append(Gtrain_data['input'[train_Gbatch_order[j + i*batch_size], :, :, :])     
input_t = np.array(input_t)
batch_z= np.array(input_z)`
```

Now, I want to run the optimizer as following:

```
_ = sess.run(g_opt, feed_dict={input_images: input_t, input_z: batch_z, lr_G: learning_rate_G})
```

But I get the unhashable type: 'list'.
So, how can I feed multiple  "LIST" inputs through `feed_dict` in tensorflow??

Answer (score 0):

Only `hashable` objects can be dictionary keys. So `lists` can not while `tuples` can.

I'm not 100% sure but probably you wanted to create `feed_dict` like this:

```
feed_dict = {'input_images': input_t, 'input_z': batch_z, 'lr_G': learning_rate_G}
```

Here keys are strings that is names for values. For example, name `'input_images'` for variable `input_t` which is `numpy array` according to the line `input_t = np.array(input_t)`. That is how dictionaries are used most of the time - to create mapping between names (keys) and variables (values).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use feed_dic like what you said I get the error like: : Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'input_images' looks like an (invalid) Operation name, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".

Comment: @FaranakSo My answer is all about dictionaries in Python. But the problem seems to originate from the way you use Tensorflow. Error says you do it wrong. I'm not very experienced with Tensorflow. I guess, for example, `input_images` variable should be something like `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[...])` where `shape` depends on the shape of `input_t` and what `g_opt` operation does.